# Add a new date column in a file

Tags: hive

I want to add a new date column into the file which shows current system date. I have looked at a similar question, but in that question, answers are suggesting to hard code the values, but I would like to add a new column into the file that is showing current system date.

Sample data in the file

```
First_Name Last_name
Shaun      Washington
James      Dean
```

After new column is added, data in the file should look like

```
First_Name Last_name   Date
Shaun      Washington  01/24/2018
James      Dean        01/24/2018
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For current date you can simply used `CURRENT_DATE` function.
in lower versions, looks like hive CURRENT_DATE is not available, hence you can use (it works in Hive 0.14+)

```
Select First_Name, Last_name,TO_DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP())) as Date from table;
```

In higher versions say hive 2.0, you can use :

```
Select First_Name, Last_name, CURRENT_DATE as Date from table
```

Comment: Will this add a new column in the file?

Comment: But I have not created a table with this file yet. I want to add a new date column first and then add all of the columns into the table. Also the file is stored in HDFS.

Comment: first create a table and add a new column as per above query.

Comment: I am told to create the table after I add date column into the file. Is there any linux command that would let me add the column into the file.

Comment: you can do this by using python... just used `time.time()`

Comment: Is it possible to do it in Linux instead of Python?